# set width of UITableViewCell text

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a uitableview with uitableviewcells however some of my text is so long its going right to the edge of the cell, where my accessory tick view is going to be when selected..

I am currently wrapping the text if it extends beyond the width and it goes onto the second line.. However I was hoping there is a nice way to restrict the width of this UITableViewCell label.

Comment: u want to fit text in given width of label?

Comment: nope sorry, dynamic text in the (label as a fixed width)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath: function. The first time you create your cell:

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil)
 {
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
   cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
   cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
   cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
 }
```

Now specify how large your UITableViewCell will be, so do that in your heightForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSString *str = [[arrTexts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // filling text in label  
  CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, 100); // change width and height to your requirement
 CGSize strSize = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17] constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap] //dynamic height of string depending on given width to fit

 return (10+strSize.height+10) // caculate on your bases as u have string height
}
```

Comment: I couldnt get this to work, it just kept increasing the height of my cell but did not effect anything to do with my width.. still trying maybe i fluffed something up.. but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Set the width of the `textLabel`

```
cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.textLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.textLabel.frame.origin.y, 280, cell.textLabel.frame.size.height);
```

thats all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need subclass `UITableViewCell` to override `-layoutSubviews`... call `super`, then frame your label appropriately. Constraints my be of some help, but I haven't used them on iOS yet. (Assuming the problem is the built-in layout function make the label as wide as it needs to be to accommodate your text)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do so.

1) Create a custom UITableViewCell class, add your UILabels with whatever position & size you want. And then use it in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

2) Else, don’t use default UILabels of UITableViewCell ie. textLabel & detailTextLabel, add your own UILabels in cell with whatever position & size you want.

Comment: actually, #2 is not bad--you can position your custom label as you like and set your _autoresizingMask_ to `UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth`, although this probably still requires subclassing.