# How to limit width of textLabel in UITabelViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, textlabel

I want to restrict the width of `textLabel` of `UITabelViewCell` as it contains a image on its right side.

I don't want to use `UILabel` or subclass `UITabelViewCell`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085174/set-width-of-uitableviewcell-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `accessoryView` property for the image on the right. This should prevent the label from getting too wide and truncating the text.

```
[cell setAccessoryView:<your image view>];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3; // set the numberOfLines
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
```

OR

```
 CGRect aFrame = cell.textLabel.frame;
 aFrame.size.width = 100;  // for example
 cell.textLabel.frame = aFrame;
```

Comment: what does your textLabel.frame contain?